# QA Algorithm for Q Processing

Tags: algorithm, parsing, nlp

`What Algorithm/method do I use for a Question Answering System's Question Processing?`

I have been searching possible algorithms for my Question Answering System, the only thing that I think that would be possible to use is `Parsing` but I have asked about parsing in my last question and with the answers there i think its not possible to be used?(I'm not sure).

My idea of using `Parsing` is by Cutting the question into pieces word per word and then it will go through a Storage of Words that would determine what Kind of Word(noun,adjective,verb,etc) is being said. My purpose of using `Parsing` is to remove or rather to determine the Topic of the question.

The other idea of mine is the `ChatterBot`. A Chatterbot uses a query of words? Correct me if I'm not mistaken and those words are assigned to another Word. It would randomly choose a word from its Query.

Example: User's Statement: Hello > ChatterBot's  Possible Replies: Hi,Hello,Hey

I'm not quite sure what is the possible method/algorithm to use in a Question Answering, I have read the Wikipedia post : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering but I do not quite understand what algorithm to use in `Question Processing`.

Thank you.

PS: I'm developing in Javascript. Q = Question

Comment: As you can see from the Wikipedia article you link to, question answering is not a simple algorithm - it is an entire field of research.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a naive bayes classifier in order to look at the questions and determine their subject.  You'd need a lot of training data and a fairly narrow domain.

The sophisticated responses to this problem involve a lot of machine inference techniques which are a bit out of my skill level to explain extremely well.  My idea is to use a markov network in which each word has an edge to one or two words next to it. A series of tests are applied to each word which indicate likely memberhood of that word to one of its possible meanings (For example, Mark is more likely a name if it's capitalized, but if the next word is 'a' it probably is used in the sense of a verb.)  From there the machine can attempt to determine the actual meaning of the sentence, which will rely on the use of, again, unimaginably large amounts of training data.

Coursera's Probabilistic Graphical Models class (Probably their NLP class too) would probably be the best resource if you're interested in becoming skilled in this area.  (PGM is the only reason I know anything about this!)

Answer (score 0):

here's a great book, you may need to read to get a lot of stuff related to NLP, and Question answering systems [http://www.amazon.com/Speech-Language-Processing-2nd-Edition/dp/0131873210](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873210)

the book has a full section (V.Applications) that will help you a lot to develop a good system.
but note that the book is discussing theories and algorithms only (no code)

it's not about parsing text only, you'll need to understand the context to provide better answer. actually you need to extract some keywords and ignore everything else.

also you may read in topics Keywords (Bag of words), algorithms like (TF/IDF).